# Passing Multiple Attributes to a Component

Tags: reactjs

Can someone explain exactly what is happening in the below code snippet?

```
someObject: { obj1, obj2 }

<SomeComponent { ...{obj1, obj2} } />
```

someObject is being destructured and then passed as attributes into SomeComponent. What I don't get is why there are brackets around both after a rest operator. What exactly is this doing?

Answer (score 1):

```
<SomeComponent { ...{obj1, obj2} } />
```

The outer `{}` is used for including any javascript expression inside the JSX.

The inner `{}` after `...` is an object literal. It creates a new object with the properties `obj1` and `obj2`.